# function javascript for both active label.hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big problem: I have basically two label

```
 <label id="label1" class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm label1 active" onclick="showSomething($(this));">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="Radio2" />Label1</label>
                    <label id="label2" class="btn btn-transparent grey-salsa btn-circle btn-sm label2" onclick="showSomething($(this));">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" class="toggle" id="Radio3" />Label2</label>
```

and the javascript function `showSomething`

I have to Show 3 graphics and the problem is that. I want to show one of the graph when two label are  activated so the both label should be active
and so I do this:

```
function showSomething (labelJQ) {
    if (labelJQ.hasClass ('active'))
        return;
    else {
        if (labelJQ.hasClass('label1')) {
            if (labelJQ.hasClass('label2')) {
                $('#Chart1').hide();
                $('#Chart2').hide();
                $('#Chart1,2').show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but does not give me any results, does not know `label.hasClass` for both at the same time if I do one and then the other works perfectly but to me I do not need so - is there a way that can I do?

Comment: There are several points that I think need clarifying.  What is the exact functionality you are aiming for?  What do you mean by a label being "active".  Do you mean the radio button is selected? This is standard radio button behaviour.  Also, in your html you dont need to nest the radio buttons *inside* the label element.   Finally, your jQuery calls appear to be invalid.  For example, remove spaces and use lowercase:  `$('#myId').hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to interpret your question, so please provide further clarification if this does not do what you had hoped for, but...

I think your jQuery is a significant part of the issue here.  I believe it is clearer if you assign the <s>click</s> change handler in a way similar to the following:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    $('.chart').hide();

    if (this.id == 'option1') {
        $('#chart1').show();
    } else if (this.id == 'option2') {
        $('#chart2').show();
    }
});
```

I have put together a demo from your original input here:

https://jsfiddle.net/g8wkwdo4/2/

Hope that helps!

Comment: hello and thanks for the answers, I apologize if I was not very clear, it is almost what I want except the fact that I want it for 2 radio buttons selected at the same time, when the two radio buttons are on at the same time I have to show a graph but I have many radio buttons so I have to check which of the radio buttons are selected to show the corresponding chart.

Comment: Ah ok. Hopefully the demo should be enough to go on.  For multiple, independent radio buttons, be sure to change their `name` attributes to distinct values.